# Installation fails when trying to install Unity AndroidPlayer on macOS

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, macos-sierra, failed-installation

I'm having trouble installing the latest version of Unity's AndroidPlayer (v5.6.1f1) on my macOS MacBook Pro (macOS version 10.12.5)

I already have Unity installed and working, but all I'm trying to do is add ability to run my games on an Android device (I have Android SDK configured and working from my previous Android App development)

I'm running the pkg file that I got from Unity called `UnitySetup-Android-Support-for-Editor-5.6.1f1.pkg` and go through the installation process, but after the installer begins to install the software, it fails and looking at the logs it states that `PackageKit: Session UUID file exists - will not overwrite [some long path]/[filename].activeSandbox`

Anyone knows what could be the problem? I've even restarted my Mac / re-downloaded the file with no avail...

[image: Failure message]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to install Android support using the full Unity3D installer and making sure that the Android support is selected. Could be a specific problem with the AndroidPlayer installation package.

Answer (score 22):

I managed to defeat the issue by installing the required packages from the Unity Hub, instead of manually downloading & installing.

Start Unity -> click `Installs` -> reveal `Add Modules` by clicking the vertical 3 dots and select the modules required by clicking on the checkboxes.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else runs into this and is unable to see the `Add Modules` button described in the other answer, you need to install the editor through Unity Hub in order to see that option.

I removed the old editor, went to:

https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive

and then clicked the `Unity Hub` button for the specific version I was using. That way you're able to Add Modules :)

Comment: Jan 2022 Update: This comment is still relevant even in the new Unity Hub 3.0.0-beta.7. If you have any previous versions of the Editor that *weren't* installed through the Hub, simply uninstall them, and use the Hub to install the desired version of the Editor. Then you'll see the `Add Modules` option when clicking the three dots.

Comment: You can only install the `intel` version through the hub. The `silicon`  version for M1 mac can only be installed standalone. This is an oversight on Unity's part.